# ng-init in ng-repeat shows only the last item info

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-init

I want to loop through items like this:

```
<section class="col-sm-4" data-ng-controller="PredictionsController" data-ng-init="findMyPredictions()">
    <div class="games">
        <div class="game-row" ng-repeat="prediction in predictions" ng-init="getGame(prediction.game_id)">
            <a class="button primary alt block" href="#!/predictions/{{prediction._id}}">
                <span class="home flag {{gameInfo.team1_key}}"></span>
        <span class="middle">
            <span class="date">{{gameInfo.play_at | date: 'd.MM HH:mm'}}</span>
            <span class="versus">{{gameInfo.team1_title}} - {{gameInfo.team2_title}}</span>
        </span>
                <span class="away flag {{gameInfo.team2_key}}"></span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

But the output is just X times the same info:
[image]
Although the request is done correctly:
[image]

Any idea what is wrong here?

UPDATE:
My getGame function:

```
$scope.getGame = function (game_id) {
    $scope.gameInfo = {};
    $http.get('/games/' + game_id)
    .success(function (data) {
        $scope.gameInfo = data;
    });

};
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are overwriting `gameInfo` every time.  So by the time it renders, it is just showing the last one three times.  You need to do it more like:

```
<div class="game-row" ng-repeat="prediction in predictions" ng-init="getGame(prediction)">
```

notice we pass in the `prediction` object, not just the id.  And then you can do:

```
$scope.getGame = function (prediction) {
  prediction.gameInfo = {};
  $http.get('/games/' + game_id)
  .success(function (data) {
    prediction.gameInfo = data;
  });
};
```

And thin in your html, instead of `gameInfo.whatever` you will do `prediction.gameInfo.whatever`, that way each prediction has it's own variable, and you aren't overwriting your single copy of that variable.

For example:

```
<span class="date">{{gameInfo.play_at | date: 'd.MM HH:mm'}}</span>
```

would become

```
<span class="date">{{prediction.gameInfo.play_at | date: 'd.MM HH:mm'}}</span>
```

Comment: It does not work for me, I updated my question so you can see my function. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Is the instruction `prediction.gameInfo = {};` really necessary?