# AngularJS - How to get element from ng-init?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-init

In AngularJS, I have a ng-repeat for . Now what I want to do -

On ng-repeat, I want to do ng-init like

```
<tr ng-repeat="blah in blah" ng-init($event) />
```

The $event works fine with ng-click($event). How to do the same for ng-init?

Comment: Why would you like to do it ? why $event ?

Comment: If you need the element in ng-init defined inside the controller then get it via dependency injection `$element`

Comment: for each ng-repeat, i want to check if the tr DOM has something in each record and update a button in that record. so to amke that check, i want to make a call.

Comment: check this if this could help u http://stackoverflow.com/a/24173892/4817575

Answer (score 1):

In HTML

```
<tr ng-repeat="blah in blahs"  ng-init="$last && done()" />
```

Inside your controller

```
function myControllerFunc($scope, $element){
    $scope.done= function(){
       //do something with $element
    }
}
```

Comment: you mean you can handle the elemetn suing $element?

Comment: yes $element will be the element to which the controller is bound.

Comment: But ng-init does not work because ng-init is called before the ng-repeat finishes. Now how?

Comment: Yes your correct ng-init will be called initially, check my edit above does this fix your problem? Now done will be called after the last is encountered

Answer (score 0):

In ng-init cannot exists $event. Use a directive.

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
   <input type="text" my-ng-init="myFunc"><br>
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.directive('myNgInit', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
     myNgInit: '&'
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attributes) {
    scope.myNgInit()(element);
    }
  };
});

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
   $scope.myFunc= function($element) {
    console.log($element);
   }
});
</script>
```