# How to keep previous variable that got set by a function when using ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

So, I have this ng-repeat where I call a class to set the text if the text attribute has content. This text attribute which in turn will be get binded in the html side. However, only the last variable that got set will be reflected even with the previous data in the repeater.

Here is my code

```
<div ng-repeat="x in data">
     <p ng-init="setText(x.text);">{{ ::titleText}}</p>
</div>

$scope.setText = function(text) {
        $scope.titleText = text;
        if (!$scope.titleText) {
            $scope.titleText = 'Blabla';
        }
};
```

For example if i have

```
x[0].text = '';
x[1].text = '';
x[2].text = '';
x[3].text = 'Test';
```

My expectations would be that x[0-2].text would equals to 'Blabla' but it ends up being 'Test'

I am not sure how to solve this issue.

Comment: what does your data contain?

Comment: It contain's objects/. Each object would look like x : {text: 'xxx', name: 'yyy', date: 'xxdatexx'}

Comment: if you can show me a complete example I can help you. bits and pieces is not sufficient .. update your post with full detail.

Answer (score 0):

Believe your use of `ng-init` is improper.  Per [the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit):

> This directive can be abused to add unnecessary amounts of logic into
>   your templates. There are only a few appropriate uses of ngInit, such
>   as for aliasing special properties of ngRepeat, as seen in the demo
>   below; and for injecting data via server side scripting. Besides these
>   few cases, you should use controllers rather than ngInit to initialize
>   values on a scope.

Potentially related is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24172745/ng-init-in-ng-repeat-shows-only-the-last-item-info) re. `ng-init` within `ng-repeat`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question (what do you mean by 'class'?  css class? JS class?).

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21351988/angular-js-ng-repeat-and-loop-conditions) SO may be pertinent.

OTOH, if you are trying to set a DOM element's class per what an array element attribute contains within an ng-repeat, this is how you can do it (pseudo code):

```
<div ng-repeat="x in data">

  <pre ng-class="{'class-a':x.text ==='whatever-a', 'class-b':x.text==='whatever-b'}"></pre>
</div>
```

Something along these lines, where class-a and class-b are defined in your css.

Hope this helps.