# Angular ng-repeat not showing data on laravel?

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel

The console shows that the posts were retrieved successfully, the backend works fine without the angular compatibility.

and its supposed to retrieve post data.

> angular.js:12701 XHR finished loading: GET
>   "http://127.0.0.1:8000/auth/posts".

however it shows 5 empty divs like the following

[image]

main.js

```
$http.get('/auth/posts').then(function(data){
    $scope.myposts = data;

});
```

PostController

```
   public function getPosts()
    {

        $posts = Post::all();
        return json_encode($posts);
    }
```

Route

`Route::get('auth/posts', 'HomeController@getPosts');`

the html file

```
<div id="mypost" class="col-md-8 panel-default" ng-repeat="post in myposts">
    <div id="eli-style-heading" class="panel-heading"><% post.title %></div>
        <div class="panel-body panel">
            <figure>
                <p> <% post.body %></p>

            </figure>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you post the `$scope.myposts` values ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to access the data property from the response, I think you need,

```
$http.get('/auth/posts').then(function(data){
    $scope.myposts = data.data;

});
```

Comment: it worked thanks :), ill approve as soon as it let me

Comment: another thing, when i post it doest show automatically i have to refresh the page to see the new post. any recommondations ?

Comment: load it on the ng-init

Comment: just apply ng-init on the div tag where i have ng-repeat on ?

Comment: call the request to your api on ng-init with a function

Comment: `<div id="mypost" class="col-md-8 panel-default" ng-init ng-repeat="post in myposts">`does this look right ?

Comment: no you should have a function which calls the the api and get myposts

Comment: something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24172745/ng-init-in-ng-repeat-shows-only-the-last-item-info