# Angular model doesn't update after ng-click

Tags: php, angularjs

the ng-repeat model doesn't update after a user clicks submit, it will only show on refresh, i reviewed a similar [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24172745/ng-init-in-ng-repeat-shows-only-the-last-item-info), but i couldn't connect the dots. A user recommended i do a ng-init, but i don't think im doing it right.

with ng-init it shows no data, without ng-init and removing the angular function it shows posts but doesn't update the model after click.

note:the angular brackets are replaced because laravel blade doesn't like it

html

```
    <div id="mypost" class="col-md-8 panel-default" ng-init="getPosts()" ng-repeat="post in myposts">
        <div id="eli-style-heading" class="panel-heading"><% post.title %></div>
            <div class="panel-body panel">
                <figure>
                    <p> <% post.body %></p>

                </figure>
            </div>


    </div>
```

Main.js

```
// this doens't show posts when i use ng-init
$scope.getPosts = function(){

    $http.get('/auth/posts').then(function(data){
        $scope.myposts = data.data;
    });



};

// this shows posts without ng-init but doesn't update when a user adds data


$http.get('/auth/posts').then(function(data){
    $scope.myposts = data.data;
});
```

**Updated Again**

network error

[image]

[image]

PostController.php

```
public function storePost(Request $request)
{
    $data = request()->validate([
     'title' => 'required|max:120',
     'body' => 'required|max:1000'
    ]);

    $data['user_id'] = auth()->user()->id;

    $post = Post::create($data);


    // return redirect('/home')->withMessage('A new post was created.');

    return Response::json(array('success' => true));
}
```

[image]

Comment: angular doesn't understand the blade syntax.  Consider using `ng-bind` if Laravel is throwing errors on the mustache syntax.

Comment: Have you tried adding a `$scope.$apply();` after you assign the data to `$scope.myposts`? The problem is that the promise resolution is outside of Angular's digest cycle so it doesn't know that it needs to refresh the UI unless you tell it to.

Comment: @SteveDanner ng-bind didn't work im still unable to see posts.

Comment: @Lex i tried that, i still was unable to see posts

Comment: if i remove the get posts function, and just leave it as `$http.get('/auth/posts').then(function(data){
        $scope.myposts = data.data;

    });` and remove the ng-init i can see the posts but then again it doesn't update when a post has been made

Comment: @SteveDanner this is what i currently got, https://jsfiddle.net/xf20j22u/

Comment: @OwlMan please provide the $scope.http.post request ...

Comment: @OwlMan If your code is the same as the fiddlejs, you MISTYPED your variable name ! You wrote $scope.POSTS.push(data), instead of $scope.MYPOSTS.push(data) !!

Answer (score 1):

Don't use ng-init except in cases where you are aliasing a special property of ng-repeat like `$last` or `$even` for nested ng-repeats.  If you want a function to trigger immediately just call it in the controller or service/factory it is defined in.

https://jsfiddle.net/xf20j22u/1/

```js
var app = angular.module('eli', []);

app.config(function($interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('<%');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('%>');
});

app.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope, $http, $timeout){
 $scope.posts = {};
  $scope.myposts = [{title:"titillating title",body:"Hot boddy"}]
 $scope.addPost = function(){
  
  $http.post('/auth/post', {
   title: $scope.post.title,
   body: $scope.post.body

  }).then(function(data, status, headers, config){
   $scope.posts.push(data); 
  
  });

 };

 $scope.getPosts = function(){

  $timeout(function(){
          debugger;
          $scope.myposts = [{title:"something new",body:"It's my body"}]
        },3000)
  //$http.get('/auth/posts').then(function(data){
  // $scope.myposts = data.data;
  // $scope.$apply();
  //});
 };
  $scope.getPosts();



});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/angular.js"></script>
<div  ng-app="eli" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  
  <div id="mypost" class="col-md-8 panel-default" ng-repeat="post in myposts">
    <div id="eli-style-heading" class="panel-heading">
      <% post.title %>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body panel">
      <figure>
        <p>
          <% post.body %>
        </p>

      </figure>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Working version above can replace $timeout with $http they both call $apply for you so don't call it again (only need to call $apply if you write your own things that async do work then update the model and you want to trigger a view refresh, angular event handlers and services do it for you)

Comment: thank you will keep that in mind for sure, but that still doesn't solve my problem. I can retrieve posts without ng-init but it will not update on when a user trys to add a post.

Comment: Think ng-bind and things were just getting in the way really can't say exactly what's wrong since I had to add some context for getting the ng-app and controller running there, in place of the timeout could use $http, both $http and $timeout (and all the handlers like ng-click) call $apply for you under the hood.

Comment: i appreciate your effort, but im still having the same problem, a user can add a post ok, but it just doesn't update( the ajax way) only on refresh it shows the new data, ill upvote it but it doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: No problem :). Drop a `debugger;` statement in the success callback and make sure it actually does the call to push the item into the array if not check the network tab to see if the response is a 200 OK or something else

Comment: @OwlMan shaunhusain said it earlier. Your callback isn't called, thus the array isn't updated because you never enter the callback.

Comment: @Sorikairo what should i put in the callback ?. im starting to understand the problem.

Comment: @OwlMan the problem seems to be serverside. The post request may never answer, so the callback isn't called. Check your code server side :)

Comment: ~angular.js:12701 XHR finished loading: GET "http://127.0.0.1:8000/auth/posts".`  looks fine

Comment: however, when i add a post i get this 

`angular.js:12701 POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/auth/post 500` but when i refresh the page i see my new post

Comment: Hit F12 in chrome then go to the network tab and just make sure when you trigger the call out on page load or whenever it actually gives a 200 OK from the browser perspective, sounds alright but good to see the response the browse got.... yeah so 500 is internal server error angular will trigger error response callback for that not success, the server needs to respond that all is well, so server side issue or bad request object or something making the server puke all over itself....gross

Comment: @OwlMan Wait ! Can you post your POST request call code ? It's where the problem is. You have a 500 error, so it doesn't answer properly to your call, so your callback aren't called.

Comment: @OwlMan you forgot to put the most important piece of code, the post request made in angular is the key. You probably forgot to put an error callback, and it doesn't call your success callback as it's a 500

Comment: @Sorikairo i just updated tell me what you think, thanks

Comment: @OwlMan missing the $scope.http.post part, which is the key :/

Comment: I did, i just updated. are you talking about something else.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159009/discussion-between-sorikairo-and-owl-man).

Answer (score 1):

With the help of another @Sorikairo we were able to solve the problem, i didn't want to post the answer because i was lazy, but i need to help the people who ever encounter a very similar problem when using laravel. Here is the updated code.

Main.js

```
var app = angular.module('eli', []);

app.config(function($interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('<%');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('%>');
});

app.controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){


    $scope.posts = {};

    $scope.addPost = function(){

        $http.post('/auth/post', {
            title: $scope.post.title,
            body: $scope.post.body

        }).then(function(data, status, headers, config){
            console.log(data);  
            $scope.myposts.push(data.data);


        });

        $scope.post.title = '';
        $scope.post.body = '';

    };

    $scope.getPosts = function(){

        $http.get('/auth/posts').then(function(data){
            $scope.myposts = data.data;
        }).then(function(data, status, header, config){
        });



    };


    $scope.getPosts();





}]);
```

i needed to add

the response class to my php file

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Post;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;

class PostController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function storePost(Request $request)
    {
        $data = request()->validate([
         'title' => 'required|max:120',
         'body' => 'required|max:1000'
        ]);

        $data['user_id'] = auth()->user()->id;

        $post = Post::create($data);

        $response = new Response(json_encode($data));
        $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json'); 


        // return redirect('/home')->withMessage('A new post was created.');

        return $response;
    }
```

it works now thank you everyone